# Any book/paper recommendation for Appell sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am interested in Appell polynomials and I would like to read further about it. I am having a hard time looking for references and papers. Would also appreciate it if you can suggest some preliminary readings as I have a limited mathematical background. Thank you!

Comment: Anything wrong with the references supplied in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell_sequence)?

Comment: Oh, I checked it but I cannot find any english translation of appell's original paper. Another interesting paper I would like to read (http://rivista.math.unipr.it/fulltext/1967-8/1967-8-355.pdf) has no english translation I can find yet.

Comment: There seem to be lots of references for the things...see [this article](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Appell_polynomials) and  the references it gives, for example.